# P-value of the predicted data in Matlab step-wise linear regression

Tags: matlab, linear-regression, p-value

I use Matlab's `stepwiselm` to find a fit to my training data. The result model has a "total p-value" of the f-statistics that Matlab shows it. Now I want to use this model on a test dataset and calculate its p-value to determine how significant the prediction is.

Matlab has 3 commands to evaluate the model on a new data ([link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/linear-regression-model-workflow.html#btb50r6)). But none of these commands automatically report a f-statistic p-value. Using `predict` and the model from `stepwiselm` for instance, returns the predicted response. Now the question is how I can find the p-value from the predicted values of the test set and their true values.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not seen a built-in [LinearModel class](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/linearmodel-class.html) function that evaluates explained variance of extrapolated data (which seems odd).

F-statistic compares the residual errors of a full-model (created by `stepwiselm`) to the residual errors of a reduced-model (`y_hat = mean(y)`). This calculation is well [described here](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat501/node/295).

#### Sum-squared errors (SSE)

Determine the SSE for the full-model and reduced-model

```
[Ypred] = predict(mdl,Xnew);

SSE_F = sum((Ynew - Ypred).^2); % full model SSE
SSE_R = sum((Ynew - mean(Ynew)).^2); % reduced model SSE
```

#### Degrees of Freedom (df)

I am not certain, but I think `df` will be determined by the training-data, not the test-data. I would double check with [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) If you are uncertain.

```
% Change Xold,Xold to XNew,YNew if df is determined  by test-data
mdl_F = stepwiselm(Xold,Yold,...); % same parameters as original mdl
mdl_R = stepwiselm(Xold,Yold,'constant');

df_F = mdl_F.DFE; % n - p
df_R = mdl_R.DFE; % n - 1
```

#### F* Statistic

Now we can compare the full-model and the reduced-model

```
MSR = (SSE_R - SSE_F) / (df_R - df_F);
MSE = SSE_ F/df_F;

F = MSR/MSE;
```

#### P Value

Now that we have our `F*` statistic, we will compare that to `F` distribution to determine a P-value.
[df here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/617735/multiple-regression-degrees-of-freedom-f-test)

```
df_num = mdl_F.NumPredictors; % p - 1 + 1 (matlab doesn't include intercept as a predictor)
df_den = mdl_F.DFE; % n - p
```

[F* to F here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/40122-p-value-of-f-test)

```
p_val = fcdf(F,df_num,df_den);
```